# invalid xml syntax in jersey webservices using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, web-services, rest, jaxb

I am using jersey web services which consumes POST request as an xml and produces response as an xml.
I am using JAXB to marshal/Unmarshal xml into Java bean. Here "TestCall" is a class which stores all the attributes specified in request,but in case XML is malformed(i.e. end tag missing) in request, i need to return ERROR code in response XML. so how to handle these scenario ?

Here is my code:

```
@POST 
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Path("/testCall")
@Override
public TestCallOutput postCall(TestCall testCall) 
    return myService.acceptCallData(testCall);
}
```

I am marshal the xml using below 2 classes:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRegistry;
@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {


/**
 * Create a new ObjectFactory that can be used to create new instances of schema 
 * 
 */
public ObjectFactory() {
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link TestCall }
 * 
 */
public Ivrcall createTestcall() {
    return new Testcall();
}
```

}

and

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {

})
@XmlRootElement(name = "testcall")
public class TestCall {

/** The method. */
@XmlElement(required = true)
protected String method;

/** The dateref. */
@XmlElement(required = true)
protected String dateref;

/** The timeref. */
@XmlElement(required = true)
protected String timeref;

/** Getters and Setters of elements 
... */
}
```

I need to return response in xml like below:
    `<testcall> 
    <status>ERROR</status> 
    <msgid>0001</msgid> 
    <msgtxt>INVALID XML DOCUMENT</msgtxt>
    </testcall>`

Comment: Show the code with which you unmarshal the XML that might have invalid XML syntax.

Comment: i have provided the code in actual query

Answer (score 0):

The stack should handle this for you by returning a 500 error to the client. You don't need to do any work.

Edit: if you insist on implementing this (I would push back if I were you, unless you're required to be compliant to an existing interface), you should add a JAX-WS handler (`javax.xml.ws.handler.Handler`) and override `handleFault` to check for the specific exception that JAX-WS throws when it can't unmarshal the incoming message. Then create the response XML in the handler.

Comment: I need to return the response like this - <TestCall>
 <status>ERROR</status>
 <msgid>0001</msgid>
 <msgtxt>INVALID XML DOCUMENT</msgtxt>
</TestCall>

Comment: Looking for answer too. Client will receive not 500 error code, but 400 - Bad request